# CAD to GDB import using ValueTable function

Tags: arcpy, merge, cad, error-000735

I have several CAD files (DWG) that I want converted to Feature Classes within a file GDB.
Each feature class will be based on a polyline attribute "LAYER" value, so I have a query filter applied before they get loaded into the GDB.

I think my script (Python 2.7) has a problem with there being no values being written to the ValueTable. Here's the script, followed by the error message - can anyone please help?

=================================

```
# Description: Imports and merges polylines from one CAD workspace into a single feature class

import arcpy 
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "X:/GEMS_vector_data/DWG_files_sites_floors/0011-test" 
CADgdb = "X:/GEMS_vector_data/DWG_files_sites_floors/0011-test/CADToFeatures.gdb"

# Create a value table that will hold the input feature classes for Merge
vTab = arcpy.ValueTable()

# Step through each dataset in the list
for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "CAD"):
    LayerName = fd + "_level"
    # Select only the Polyine features for external walls
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fd + "/Polyline", CADgdb + LayerName, "\"Layer\" = 'AR_WALL_EXT'")
    vTab.addRow(LayerName)

# Merge the CAD features into one feature class
MergedFloorPlans =  "X:/GEMS_vector_data/DWG_files_sites_floors/0011-test/CADToFeatures.gdb/Floors01"
arcpy.Merge_management(vTab, MergedFloorPlans)
```

================================

Error msg

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "X:\GEMS_vector_data\DWG_files_sites_floors\0011-test\import_CAD_to_FBDB_01.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       arcpy.Merge_management(vTab, MergedFloorPlans)   File "D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3762, in Merge
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000735: Input Datasets: Value is required Failed to execute
>   (Merge).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today.It turns out that [ESRI sample](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00100000002q000000) that you used is wrong. they used

`for fd in arcpy.ListDatasets("*", "CAD"):`

but "CAD" is wrong, is not a valid feature type for this tool - remove it and the script will work, or use "*.dwg".